# Should I improve my duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, new-users

I have posted a question which was later flagged as duplicate. This is fine with me, as the linked answer completely covered my issue. Later, I was given criticism due to the question title, and I decided to modify it in order to address such criticism.

Was I right in modifying my question regardless of its duplicate flag?

Comment: You should think about searchability when editing duplicates. The purpose of duplicates is that they help others to better search for something with google. Don't change your wording to match the original question. Correct grammar or any information that could confuse future readers or lead them on the wrong path/give them wrong information.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, editing a duplicate question can be useful.

Suppose that a question that has been closed as duplicate is titled "How can I get rid of this error?" Surely a more descriptive title can be provided! Generally improving the terminology used is a good thing. The reason duplicates are subject to different deletion rules than other questions that are closed is that they can serve as sign posts to the questions they point to. **The better written a duplicate is, the better it can serve its purpose as a sign post.**

Comment: Likewise, a duplicate that doesn't make easier to find the canonical, is normally deleted (ignoring the fact that it may have attracted downvotes that would end up deleting it anyways),

Answer (score 27):

**Yes!**

Duplicates - if not *truly bad* - remain on this site to guide the users to the correct answer, without having the same Q&A ten times.

So, since your question is here to stay, improving its quality is **never a bad thing**.

Answer (score 7):

The other answers say yes but I'd like to suggest 'maybe'. I like duplicate questions because their titles are often different enough for me to find them using google when the original question doesn't appear in my search results e.g. because the problem is different than I think it is.

If you had a title that was different from that of the 'original' question, it might have been helping point people toward the 'original' when they couldn't by themselves find the 'original'. I haven't looked at your question but if you edited the title to reflect a more complete understanding of the problem gained by finding the 'original', I think you should consider reverting your edit.

Comment: I agree so long as the title is good and descriptive.  The duplicate may be _Receive Error: abc when doing xyz()_ But the older one may be _How can I use xyz() to do blah thing_.